# Pyintsaller Execuatble RuntimeError: Script runserver not found

Tags: django, linux, pyinstaller

I used Pyinstaller to created a Django application Executable "testrun" on Linux.

Then I used the command `dist/testrun/testrun runserver: localserver:8000` to test the executable. But the error message shows:

```
RuntimeError: Script runserver not found
```

[Spec file hiddenimport used for executable building](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUMPX.png)

[Executable Runtime Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRO9i.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved: Pyinstaller is currently not supporting Django 3.x.x versions well. Uninstall Django and download Django 2.2.16 version. Then use pyinstaller to create executable. The executable now works fine.

Answer (score 6):

add `--noreload` in the end, it will solve this issue without downgrading django

```
dist/testrun/testrun runserver --noreload
```

Comment: You are a star!